# Best Method to Separate square wave and smooth wave

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, signal-detection, source-separation

I have a signal consists of a smooth wave and square waves. Is there comprehensive method can separate square wave and smooth signal? I looked for the likelihood ratio test but cannot find any approach to solving it.[image: Example signals]

Comment: Are they computer generated? If so, could you share the modeling code?.

Comment: Any chance you have multiple independent combinations of the two? If not, do you know the period of the square wave? How much information do you know about the two signals in general? More background would be helpful.